# how to override element class with group class

Tags: javascript, svg, css-specificity

I'm newbie in web, I'm creating draganddrop function in svg canvas, where I have a group of several svg elements. While dragging I want to override classes of elements with class of group. But elements classes has higher priority and application of class for group doesn't change assigned attributes for child elements.
So, how to override element class with group class? !important in .drag doesn't help.

```css
.gBox {
  fill:transparent;
  stroke-width:0.1
}
.gBox:hover{
     stroke:grey;
     stroke-dasharray:1,1
}
.rect{
    fill:transparent;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:0.5;
}
.hover:hover{
    stroke-dasharray:1,1
}
.drag{
    stroke:grey;
    stroke-dasharray:1,1    
}
```

```html
<g id="myGroup1" class="drag" style="">
  <rect id="undefined" x="20" y="10" width="30" height="10" rx="0" ry="0" class="gBox"></rect>
  <rect id="myRect1" x="20" y="10" width="10" height="10" rx="1" ry="1" class="rect hover"></rect>
  <rect id="myRect2" x="40" y="10" width="10" height="10" rx="1" ry="1" class="rect hover"></rect>
</g>
```

Comment: In your example the group has the same styles as the hovered elements. So on hover nothing will happen. Use different styles to see the changes

Comment: on hover cancels by pointer-events=none and don't forget about color (stroke), which is different. It's not big problem to add .drag class to all childs and onmouseup remove it, so it's theoretic question mainly